# What does $O_p(G)$ mean in the context of a Fitting subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, direct-product

[I asked this question as a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221796/given-g-is-a-finite-group-fg-zg-fg-zg#comment6285840_2221796) on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2221796/104041) *old, probably abandoned* question about the Fitting subgroup $F(G)$ of a group $G$.

It was stated in the question that

> $F(G)$ is the product of all $O_p(G)$ for all prime $p$.

(**Edit:** [Derek Holt pointed out below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049163/what-does-o-pg-mean-in-the-context-of-a-fitting-subgroup-of-g?noredirect=1#comment6286046_3049163) that $G$ must be finite here.)

I'm just curious. I couldn't find the notation in any of the obvious places, like in the results of a simple Google search. I'm interested in the theorem quoted above.

The closest thing I've seen before is the notation for the ring of integers in the context of algebraic number theory, which is way off.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group_theory)#The_p-core

Comment: Thank you, @LordSharktheUnknown; please would you elaborate on that to make it an answer so that I may close this question?

Comment: By the way, the result in question applies only to finite groups. For general groups $F(G)$ is not always defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$O_p(G)$ is the [*$p$-core*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group_theory)#The_p-core) of the finite group $G$. This is the intersection of all its Sylow $p$-subgroups, and is the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: This makes me wish of a group $C$ whose name sounds like "choo", just so we could have $O_p(C)$.